# $P(30 \leq \max(S_k)_{k \leq 100} < 40)$ for a symmetric simple random walk.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

> Let $S_n$ be a symmetric, simple random walk starting at $0$. Find
> $$
> P(30 \leq \max(S_k)_{k \leq 100} < 40)
> $$

So basically I want to find the probability that a simple random walk of length 100 at least once touches the line of 30 and does not cross or touch the line of 40.

Could anyone give me a hand or solve this? I wish I could show my attempt but there isn't much to show.

Comment: If $S_k$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, how are you defining $\max(S_k)_{k \le 100}$?

Comment: @user6247850 - I was wrong, it is just 1D.

Comment: Do you know how to find just $P(\max_{k \le 100}(S_k) < 40)$?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I could rephrase the original question as "How to find $P(max(S_k)_{k \leq 100} < M)$ for some M", because I noticed that $P(30 \leq \max(S_k)_{k \leq 100} < 40) = P(\max(S_k)_{k \leq 100} \leq 39) - P(\max(S_k)_{k \leq 100} \leq 29)$.

Comment: So, what is the "line at 30"? Do you mean the "square", since it's 2D?

Comment: @BenjaminWang No, I have edited the question - it is 1D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited. Sorry for the calculation mistakes committed earlier.)

You can apply the reflection principle to find out the probability $$\mathbb{P}\left(\max_{1\le i\le 100} S_i < M,\ S_{100} = 2k\right),$$ where $2k < M.$ Consider it's complement, i.e. the event where it touches the line $y=M.$ Take the part till the first time it touches that line, and reflect it in that line, so that $(0,0)$ goes to $(0, 2M).$ Now you can easily see that  $$\mathbb{P}\left(\max_{1\le i\le 100} S_i \geq M,\ S_{100} = 2k\right) = 2^{-100}\binom{100}{50+k-M}.$$ Here we have $2k<M$ and we need $k\geq M -50$ for the binomial coefficient to be positive (let's assume $M>0,$ then we would have $k\geq M-50>-50.$)

Now take $M=2\ell.$ Hence $$\mathbb{P}\left(\max_{1\le i\le 100} S_i < 2\ell\right)=\sum_{-50\le k<M/2}\mathbb{P}(S_{100}=2k) - \sum_{M-50\leq k < M/2} -  \mathbb{P}\left(\max_{1\le i\le 100} S_i \geq 2\ell,\ S_{100}=2k\right)$$ which can be evaluated as $$2^{-100}\left[\sum_{k=-50}^{\ell-1} \binom{100}{50+k} -\sum_{k=M-50}^{\ell-1}  \binom{100}{50+k-M}\right].$$
Using this, you can evaluate $\mathbb{P}(30\leq \max_{1\le k\le 100} S_k < 40).$